# My html elements are not in the proper place

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap classes and for some reason they are not working.

This is the combined templates.
The ones that are switching are `<div class="col-md-8">` and `<div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 0;">`

```
    <main role="main" class="container-flex" style="margin-left:60px; overflow:hidden;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
           ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.content-section {
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(212, 210, 210);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

The strange thing is that if I make a comment it rights itself.

[image: Picture without comment]

[image: Picture with comment]

For the full code go [here](https://about:blank)

I've tried everything I know how to do, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: please could you reduce your code to the bits that you are having and issue with - see [mcve]

Comment: Can you go to your webpage in your localhost, view source, and copy that source please. Please do this for both a post without and comment and with a comment. You'll also need to attach your css files too. Without these it's very difficult without running your code, which I don't think we would be willing to do. I also think your `col-8` vs `col-4` thing looks to be for alerts rather than the anything else.

Comment: I have added the files to the GitHub link

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your HTML examples I see that in the Source With Comment your col-md-4 container is inside row, on your other example its outside the row.

Without knowing how your HTML is generated I cannot say what is wrong but that is at least why according to your examples.

After further investigation of layout.html the only thing I can think of is that you have an additional closing div in your `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` which corresponds with an opening div inside of your `{% if messages %}`, that would explain why it works when you have comments.